# Must two plugs of USB 3.0 Y cable be connected to the same device?

Tags: power-supply, usb-3

I have a USB device which I connect to my laptop. It had a "not enough power" issue, hence I brought a Y cable to solve it.

I just find that the remaining port is USB 2.0 and it is physically far away from my 3.0 port.

Hence my question: is it safe if the power (i.e. the extra) cable connects to a USB hub or is directly connected to the power supply?

Comment: You should really avoid Y cables, but if your device requires it, plug both into an externally powered hub and connect that one to the notebook with a single cable. You might also notice that the external power also avoids the need for the Y in many cases.

Comment: @eckes From what I search in Internet, A port have a maximum power output. If I connect a powered hub to my notebook, won't the power still not enough? Or I misunderstood your " powered hub"?

Comment: The maximum power output (per port) should only be delivered after a handshake. Y cables don’t do that so depend on the minimum power output. External powered hubs are usually dumber and provide more without negotiation (Besides they often rate higher in supported current)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad idea.

If you're lucky it works.
If you're not lucky it can potentially do electrical damage to one (or more) of the 3 devices involved.

If you really can't reach the 2nd port on your laptop use a simple USB extension cable to give the 2nd plug a longer wire. Much safer.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, So it is okay that the y cable connect its data cable to 3.0port and the power to the 2.0 port?

Comment: That’s fine. Main thing is that both plugs share a common electrical ground. Your laptop will provide that for all its ports, but another power source will not have a common ground with your laptop.